# Выбор: опустить местоимение или нет

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения, выбор-варианта

Возьмём две фразы:

*Не делай вид, что ты меня не замечаешь.*
*Не делай вид, что не замечаешь меня.*

На мой взгляд, фразы одинаково хорошо звучат. Местоимение тут не избыточно, как во фразах, когда оно повторяется, типа *"Я сказал ему, что **я** уже всё сделал".*

*Тогда от чего зависит выбор, произнести местоимение или нет? Чисто от вкуса или желания автора?*

Answer (score 2):

Не делай вид, что **ты меня** не замечаешь.

Мне эта фраза кажется избыточной, плохо подходящей для разговорного (очень экономного) стиля. Так как ясно, что разговаривают двое, **одно из местоимений можно опустить**, например:

Не делай вид, что **ты** не слышишь. [М. М. Рощин. Спешите делать добро (1979)]

И не делай вид, что не знаешь **меня…** [Дина Рубина. На солнечной стороне улицы (1980-2006)]

Поэтому лучше выбрать второй вариант: Не делай вид, что не замечаешь меня.

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла! Ну что ж, тем проще, если лучше ориентироваться на один вариант (который мне нравится).

Answer (score 1):

В английском местоимение было бы необходимым, у нас же глагол «замечаешь» явно указывает, к кому обращается говорящий.

Я бы сказал, что фраза («по умолчанию», абстрагируясь от языка) предполагает местоимение, но русский язык позволяет его опустить без последствий. (По сути оно в таком случае всё равно незримо останется там.)

P.S. Лично я употребляю местоимение, когда нахожусь вне поля зрения того, к кому обращаюсь, иначе — опускаю. То есть для меня выбор продиктован целесообразностью.

Comment: Спасибо, Ильдар! В английском-то да.

Answer (score 1):

Выбор зависит от того, насколько для говорящего важна ритмическая сбалансированность фразы (распределение ударения по слогам и пр.). Если это должно стать стихотворной строкой, подойдёт только *первый* вариант - попробуйте представить себе в этом качестве второй.

Comment: *Если это должно стать стихотворной строкой...* А точно, верно! Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: Попробовал представить в этом качестве второй вариант:

*Не делай вид, что не замечаешь меня.  

Не делай вид, что со мной не знакома.  

Не делай вид, что нету огня,  

Зазноба.*

Comment: Я не имел в виду возможность или невозможность рифмования с другими строками; можно и как элемент белого стиха этот вариант рассмотреть или как одностишие - он и тогда плохо воспринимается, даже если не сравнивать его с другим вариантом. Такая строка разбивает собственный ритм: хочется выбросить слог из "не замечаешь" - нужно либо отрицание убирать, либо укорачивать "замечаешь" до "знаешь". Что до экономичности, которой в других ответах аргументировался выбор, она не всегда украшает речь. Вспомним профессора Хиггинса, оценившего риторический дар мусорщика, повторявшего отдельные слова :).